# How to display results from a database in a django web page?

Tags: python, django, forms, sqlite

I have a web page built in django that shows all rows of a sqlite table in bootstrap cards. Basically each card is a row of the table.
I want to give the user the ability to filter these cards, so the page instead of showing every objects in the database's table should display only the objects relevant to the user. The result of the search can be displayed at another URL, it's irrelevant.

I can build a html form to get info from the user and I can write a python function that search the database and print out specific rows based on an input keyword,
but I can't make these things work together.

Any hint or piece of code would be a great help, unfortunately I know nothing about php so if there's a way to do so without it would be great. Thanks all.

```py
# this is my view function, it shows all the objects in the table at a #specific URL

def index_u(request):
    universities = University.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index_uni.html', {'universities': universities})
```

```html
/* this is index_uni.html */

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for university in universities %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="{{ university.image_url}}" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{university.name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{university.region}}</p>
                    <a href="{{university.page_url}}" target="_blank">Go</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

```py
#this function takes an input and diplays specific rows
#I don't know how make this works in the html page, it works fine in terminal
def search_data():
    region_choice = input("insert region here: ")
    command = "SELECT name FROM university_university WHERE region = ?;"
    c.execute(command, [region_choice])
    for row in c:
        print(row)
```

```py
#here my model
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=58, default=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=58, default=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=58, default=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=58, default=True)
    number_of_students = models.IntegerField(default=True)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default=True)
    colleges = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    scholarship = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    uni_canteen = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    page_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083, default=True)
```

Comment: Can you share your `University` model?

Comment: "unfortunately I know nothing about php"—what does PHP have to do with anything?

Comment: What does "I can't make these things work together" mean? In what way is the code you show here not doing what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: I've searched a solution in here and around the web, apparently some revolves around PHP but as I said I literally know nothing about it :(

Comment: @Skalfaro: I would really advice you to follow the Django tutorial. It explains some basics about webdevelopment, HTTP, etc. Usually with these concepts a lot is more clear.

Comment: Wait, you're just trying to filter objects using Django's ORM instead of a raw SQL query? Yeah, definitely go through the Django tutorial.

Comment: @Chris: no he did it the opposite way: using raw queries instead of the Django ORM :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, that's what I meant. He appears to know how to use `University.objects.all()`. He's got an SQL query but doesn't know how to use the result. A good solution is to do an ORM query and get an appropriate `QuerySet` back. I'm suggesting that that's what he should have asked (though as you pointed out a trip through the tutorial would do a world of good here).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Any recommendation about django tutorial or a specific topic? I watched like 15 h of them on yt but I clearly missed something

Comment: @Skalfaro: the Django website has a tutorial, that is, imho, quite good: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/ it is a "hands on" tutorial, you create a "mini-blog" website.

Comment: @Skalfaro, always use official tutorials when possible. Generally speaking, YouTube is a _terrible_ medium / source for tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a query with:

```
def index_u(request):
    region = request.GET.get('region')
    universities = University.objects.all()
    if region is not None:
        universities = universities.filter(region=region)
    return render(request, 'index_uni.html', {'universities': universities})
```

You can then create for example a form, like:

```
<form method="get" action="url-of-index_u">
    <input type="text" name="region">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<! --  render the universities -->
```

Comment: @funnydman: by using indentation, the boldface of the `.filter(region=region)` disappears.